# How to use Checked binding with radio button on item selected of the listview cell with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I am using radio button with listview and on listview item click I want to make radio button checked/selected but unfortunately not able to select the radio button.

```
                       <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="200" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                        <ListView RowHeight="45" IsVisible="true" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" BackgroundColor="#5679d1"
                                  SelectedItem="{Binding objItemSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="White">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                                <DataTemplate>  
                                    <ViewCell>

                                            <Grid>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Questions}" TextColor="Black" Grid.Column="0" 
                                                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                                </Label> 
                                                 <controls:CustomRadioButton HeightRequest="15" HorizontalOptions="End" Checked="{Binding Radiobtn}" IsVisible="true"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>  
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                        </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I've voted to close, since in my opinion this question is not understandable at all. Could you edit the question to clarify what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted the code for objItemSelected, so you may need to mix it with my answer, but to achieve what you want you should have this:

```
public object objItemSelected
{
  get => null;
  set
  {
     if (value == null)
        return;
     value.Radiobtn = true;
     onPropertyChanged(nameof(objItemSelected));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess that you want to have two event, one is ListView Itemselected, another is RadioButton check event in Listview. I do one sample about this, but I add Button in listview, replace RadioButton, you can take a look:

```
 <StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding models}" RowHeight="40" ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <Label
                                x:Name="label1"
                                Text="{Binding Name}"
                                TextColor="Black" />
                            <Button x:Name="btn1" Text="{Binding Description}" Clicked="OnButtonClick" />


                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>

  private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        testmodel model = (testmodel)e.SelectedItem;
        //Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
        DisplayAlert("Alert", model.Name, "OK");
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        StackLayout listviewiten = (StackLayout)btn.Parent;
        Label label = (Label)listviewiten.Children[0];
        DisplayAlert("Alert", label.Text, "OK");
        //Console.WriteLine(label.Text);


    }
```